# Is there any antimatter that exists as atoms?

Tags: atoms, antimatter

I recently read a few things that implied that there is [antimatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter) that we know of (have created?) that exists as atoms - which I guess means positrons and antiprotons bound together, at least.

Is this actually "real"?   I know that we've created antimatter particles (in parrticle-antiparticle pairs that appear from collisions)... I'd always assumed this was as far as we could go.

Comment: Is your question whether antimatter atoms have been observed, or whether *all* antimatter produced is in this form? Please rephrase your question (and in particular the title) to clarify.

Comment: The former.   "Have any antimatter atoms been observed (I know that antimatter particles have been observed)?"

Comment: One of the guys I work with was among the people to get an award for trapping an anti-hydrogen atom for 15 minutes (only 15 minutes because they didn't see a point in keeping it longer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihydrogen, anti hydrogen has been produced - so the answer to your question is "yes, it is real".

Comment: +1. Also see [Star Collaboration, "Observation of the antimatter helium-4 nucleus," *Nature* 473.7347 (2011): 353-356](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3312).

Comment: ... and there is an experiment at CERN comparing the spectra of anti-hydrogen and hydrogen atoms: [ALPHA](http://alpha.web.cern.ch/)

Comment: @DavidHammen but I don't know whether call it an atom, Do you call the normal alpha particles atoms?